# Proving $P \left( \bigcup_n \bigcap_{k = n}^{\infty}A_k \right) =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P \left( \bigcap_{k = n}^{\infty}A_k \right) $?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, self-learning

$P$ is a probability measure and $A_1, A_2, ... \in F$ that is a sigma algebra.

$$P \bigg( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k = n}^{\infty}A_k \bigg) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P \bigg( \bigcap_{k = n}^{\infty}A_k \bigg) $$

I am trying to prove this equality by using the definition of limit and finding for every $\epsilon > 0$ a $k \in N$ s.t.

$$ \Bigg| P \bigg( \bigcap_{k = n}^{\infty}A_k \bigg) - P \bigg( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k = n}^{\infty}A_k \bigg) \Bigg| < \epsilon    $$

for every $n \ge k$. But I am a bit stuck in finding such a $k$.

Comment: $P(\cup_n E_n) = \lim_n P(E_n)$ whenever $E_n \subset E_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and this applies here.

Comment: @Zarrax But why is that true? Is it an axiom or a definition?

Comment: @Monolite: Try to write $\cup_n E_n$ as an union of disjoint sets

Comment: @Monolite: and then apply countable additivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Monolite - it is not an axiom per se, but it easily follows from the axioms of a measure.

Put $E_{n}:=\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}.$  Notice that $E_{1}\subset E_{2}\subset E_{3}\subset\ldots$ (since if $j>l$, then $E_{j}$ is an intersection of fewer (of the same!) sets as $E_{l}$.  Now put $E:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}.$  Because the $\{E_{n}\}$ are nested, $E=\lim_{n\to\infty}E_{n}.$  Thus, our problem reduces to showing

$$(1)\;\;\;\;P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}E_{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(E_{n}\right).$$

That is, $P:\mathcal{F}\to\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is "continuous" w.r.t. monotone sequences of sets (i.e. nested increasing [unions] and nested decreasing [intersections]).

**Hint to prove (1)**

Put $B_{n}:=A_{n}-A_{n-1}$ for $n=2,3,\ldots$ and $B_{1}:=A_{1}.$  Then $B_{j}\cap B_{l}=\emptyset$ for $j\neq l$, yet $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}$.  Now apply the axiom of countable additivity.